# How does bind compare the serial number?

Tags: dns, bind, zone

Does bind9 check if the serialnumber is higher than the previous serial number before it updates or does bind9 also update if the new serialnumber is lower?

Answer (score 2):

If a refresh timer expires or when your slave nameserver gets a zone change notify then the nameserver first performs an SOA query to check the value of the new serial number.

If the value of the new serial number is higher than the current one then the [AI]XFR is performed.

You will never be in a situation where a zone is 'downgraded' to an older version.

Mind the fact that serial numbers use 'sequence space arithmetic'. This is defined in [RFC 1982](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1982.txt). What this means is that given enough increments the serial number will at some point wrap around from the beginning. It's an interesting read but you would only use this if you want to reset your serial number.